# How to set a particular resolutions on HDMI out

Tags: android

I uses OMAP5 processor with android JellyBean 4.2.2 release.  I need to set a particular resolutions on my HDMI output display. This need to be done by passing commands from application. is it possible to do this in android/kernel level? Where and all I need to modify for this ?

Thanks,

Hari

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Android SDK to support this. Screen resolutions are negotiated between the device and the display; apps do not have any input into the decision.